# How to use ALSA with android ndk?

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, alsa

I'm trying to record the audio directly with ALSA on galaxy nexus running Android 4.2.2. 
The phone has been rooted and I installed ALSA packages using AlsaMixer.

My question is when using ndk to compile my native C code of capturing audio with ALSA api, ALSA library (libasound.so) is not included in the ndk. How should I compile my code?

Should I compile ALSA in NDK as C libraries? But how will the device select which alsa packages to use since it already has one in the system?

I'm quite new to ALSA and ndk development. Sorry if the question is silly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to compile the ALSA library statically into your code.

But it might be a better idea to compile with ALSA as a dynamic library (probably by compiling alsa-lib yourself) and relying on the system library at runtime (i.e., do not *install* libasound yourself).